# Are "oil colours" the same as "oil paints," or am I buying pigments by accident?

Tags: painting, terminology, oil-paint

I was looking at these [*oil colours*](http://www.winsornewton.com/na/shop/oil-colour/winton-oil-colour) from Winsor & Newton and was just hoping someone more experienced could confirm that "Oil colours" = "Oil paints," and that I'm not inadvertently buying pigments that I need to mix with something to get the actual paint.

Comment: _I was looking at these ..._ It would still be useful if you added a link to what you found and add it to the question so we know what you are looking at as well

Comment: Thy will be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your link. That's oil paint. It's possible to purchase just the pigments and make your own paint (whatever kind of paint you choose), but pigments come in a powdered form, not in a tube.

Paint of any kind consists of pigments mixed into an adhesive. Oil paint uses oil as its base. This works because oil gets all sticky and gummy as it dries, and thus adheres the pigment to the chosen support surface.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, adding oil to ground pigment will turn it into oil paint; adding acrylic to ground pigment will turn it into acrylic paint; adding water to pigment will turn it into water colours...

So, this should be oil paint if it contains oil, and not just pigment.

(Where did you find this? Isn't there a description to the product? An image? If [this](http://www.winsornewton.com/row/shop/oil-colour) is what you've been looking at, yes this is oil paint.)

Comment: Not so much with the water colors... you still need a binder like gum arabic.